# Searching a list and displaying the matching value

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am currently using the ".contains" method to search a list and get the matching value back e.g.

List1:

```
dog bark
cat meow
lion raw
```

e.g.

```
if (List1.Contains("dog"))
{
// Return the value of this list item e.g. "dog bark"
}
```

Comment: How to find the element that contains a substring of a list and return it.

Comment: wild guess: He means anything that works like LINQ's FirstOrDefault(t=>t == "dog")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
var match = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("dog"));
if (match != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Or to display all matches:

```
foreach (var match in list.Where(x => x.Contains("dog"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```